# Why didn't the test.no work here?

Tags: java

```
public class ThisTest {
  int no = 1;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    method1();
    method2();
  }

  static void printMyNo() {
    int no = 2;                                         
    System.out.println(this.no);
  }

  static void method1() {
    int no = 10;
    printMyNo();
  }

  static void method2() {
    int no = 15;
    printMyNo();
  }
}
```

I just learnt about 'this' keyword and trying to understand it better, I wrote this code under the impression that it would give the output as:-

- 10
- 15

My understanding being that main calls the method1 and method2 methods which in turn call printMyNo method each on their own; and if I print this.no in printMyNo method, it'll print the value of no variable of whichever method called it. So since method1 and method2 both called printMyNo, it should print both the method's variable's value. But apparently it didn't happen. Please help me in understanding what I missed or perhaps misunderstood about this keyword? :/

Comment: "this" refers to the one declared in the class itself. Your "no" is never changed. The variables you define inside your methods are only visible inside the method itself. The "this" keyword is used to differentiate between two variables that have the same name (one at class level, the other one at method level)

Comment: There is no "this" in your example, as all methods are static; none of them can see the "this.no".

Comment: @Tim no, using `this` in a static method is a compile-time error.

Comment: If you want to print method level variable value, just print "no". this.no will always print the class level field value

Comment: Indeed, did not see the Static here. But I guess the OP was trying to understand the concept of "this" and tried with a test class, and in order to make it run, he made it static :)

Answer (score 2):

```
System.out.println(this.no);  // this does not even compile
```

Another thing you need to learn about `this` is that it cannot be used inside `static` methods.

---

`int no = 10;  // creates a new variable, does not change outer "no"`

You are declaring local variables of the same name as the instance field (which is not visible anyway because you are in a static method, see above). These go away when the method ends and have no effect on instance or class variables of the same name.

If you want to assign to the `no` on the class or instance, you just say `no = 10` (without the `int`), or, if that is "shadowed", because you have these local variables of the same name, `this.no = 10` (for instance variable) or `ThisTest.no = 10` (for class variable).

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `this` in a static method.

`this` refers to the current instance of a class. You don't have a current instance of the class in a `static` method, so it is a compile-time error to use it.

In order to get this to work, you'd either need to make the class-level `no` variable static:

```
static int no = 1;
```

and refer to it as

```
ThisTest.no
```

(if you have another variable in scope called `no`) or make your methods non-static, and instantiate the class in your main method:

```
ThisTest instance = new ThisTest();
instance.method1();
```

Answer (score 0):

You never change `this.no`, you just create local variables that are never used.

Pass an argument to the called method:

```
static void method1() {
  printMyNo(10);
}

static void printMyNo(int no) {
  System.out.println(no);
}
```

Comment: His code would never be able to access the `this.no` he has never created a new instance of the `ThisTest` object. All his method calls are `static`.

Comment: @JRSofty True. That's why I propose to use a method parameter instead of accessing members.

Comment: Agreed, but it doesn't really help him understand the `this` keyword that he wants to learn.

Answer (score 0):

First things first, there are some inconsistencies in your code regarding what is done and what can be done. You cannot use `this` in `static` methods, so there are other options there: either change the `no` variable to a `static` one or make your methods non-static.

Assuming that the `no` variable is a class variable (thus `static`), you can then use it in your methods as follows (example given for `method1`):

```
static void method1() {
    no = 10;
    printMyNo();
  }
```

What happens here is that the `no` variable (defined as `static` based on the above assumption) already exists, thus you do not need to redefine it. In fact defining a new `int no` inside a method will always cover the existing variable.

If you do not want `no` to be `static`, you have to alter the methods, specifically making them non-static. That is simple enough (exampe is again `method1`):

```
void method1() {
    this.no = 10;
    printMyNo();
  }
```

In this case, you access the `no` variable of the instance of the object in order to alter it. Again, redefining the variable in the method is not correct as stated above.

Last but not least, you could maybe want to use the value of the `no` variable without altering the stored value long-term. Provided it is either a class or instance variable of the same class you can do:

```
int no = no; // when it is a static variable and the method is static
int no = this.no; // when the method and variable are instance
```

This way you can alter the value locally using the new variable defined in the method as `no`.

Note that if you change any of your methods, you have to change the others too to make sure they work properly as well. Hope this is useful and helps you understand how instance and class variables and methods work!